# http.Request RequestURI field when making request in go

Tags: http, go

I dumped request from server to `[]byte` and used `ReadRequest` to make a request with `Client.Do` method. I got an error:

> http: Request.RequestURI can't be set in client requests.

Can you explain me why exactly I got this error?

Answer (score 17):

The error is clear: You are not allowed to have RequestURI set when doing a client request.

In the documentation for `http.Request.RequestURI`, it says (my emphasis):

> RequestURI is the unmodified Request-URI of the
>   Request-Line (RFC 2616, Section 5.1) as sent by the client
>   to a server. Usually the URL field should be used instead.
>   *It is an error to set this field in an HTTP client request.*

The reason why it is set is because that is what ReadRequest does when parsing the request stream.

So, you need to set the URL and clear the RequestURI if you want to send it. After making an attempt, I noticed that the URL object in the request returned from ReadRequest will not have all the information set, such as scheme and host. Due to this, you will need to set it yourself, or just parse a new URL using [Parse](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Parse) in the `net/url` package:

Here is some working code for you:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "bufio"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

var rawRequest = `GET /pkg/net/http/ HTTP/1.1
Host: golang.org
Connection: close
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; de-de) AppleWebKit/523.10.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Safari/523.10
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-us;q=0.3

`

func main() {
    b := bufio.NewReader(strings.NewReader(rawRequest))

    req, err := http.ReadRequest(b)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // We can't have this set. And it only contains "/pkg/net/http/" anyway
    req.RequestURI = ""

    // Since the req.URL will not have all the information set,
    // such as protocol scheme and host, we create a new URL
    u, err := url.Parse("http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }   
    req.URL = u

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", resp)
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/LyzKakprUQ)

Ps. play.golang.org will panic, since we don't have the permission to do http requests.

Comment: Great answer! I encountered the same problem and my use case is that I have a proxy server that takes all incoming requests from a client (browser) then I want to send each incoming request to a remote api. Is it right to create a new http request by copying from the original incoming request then send it to the remote api?